# Guided propagation in transmission lines

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, electromagnetic, propagation, waveguide

Can you help me on understanding why we may say this transmission line the propagation is guided and there is not any radiation?

[image]

It is a 2-conductors transmission line, in which the conductors are assumed to be at a very low distance. My textbook assumes that the line is open, and says that, since the currents on the wires are opposite, the EM fields cancel each other.

But, I do not understand some things:

1) How can I "see" (graphically) that tue EM fields cancel each other?

2) And if was the transmission line connected to an impedance Zl?

Answer (score 0):

That is just a very schematic drawing. You can't "see" that this is a transmission line. The text just defines it to be.

Comment: Do you know how to find something about this? Maybe an image or some explanation of this phenomenon

Comment: There's no phenomenon here! Just a book that says "look at these two black lines: imagine they are a transmission line". end of story.

Comment: Yes, but in theory it wanted to show that a transmission line does not irradiate, although there is not any graphical explanation

Comment: I don't know whether you can meaningfully prove that at all, that's the *definition* of a transmission line: Find a construct in which a specific EM/TEM wave can only propagate in one direction. You call that a transmission line.